# Xtify iOS API 2.0 Retrieving the XID

Tags: ios, xtify

How do I know when an xid is available after I register the deviceToken to the Xtify Manager?

I am doing this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    XLXtifyOptions *anXtifyOptions=[XLXtifyOptions getXtifyOptions];
    [[XLappMgr get ]initilizeXoptions:anXtifyOptions];
    [[XLappMgr get] launchWithOptions:application andOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

then

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
{
    [[XLappMgr get] registerWithXtify:devToken ];
}
```

and it is printing out the xid and other things to the console, but I need to get it in the app so I can register it with my own server (which will then use the push REST api to send messages to individual users).

I noticed that `XLappMgr` has a `-(NSString *)getXid;` method, but how do I know when I can call this? Is there a delegate method that gets called when it is available, or do I need to poll it?

Regards

Comment: We've added a backlog item to enable the alerting of successful registration. We'll update this question when its available on our SDK portal.

Comment: @Dylan please check the edit in my answer

Comment: Thank you, this is much cleaner than my other solution of using performSelector with a delay until it appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no delegate method at this moment. You are right, you would need to poll it or check for it the second time when the app comes to the foreground.

**EDIT:**

Now there is a way to get notified after successful registration with Xtify. First you need to specify the delegate -

```
[[XLappMgr get] setInboxDelegate:self]; // The delegate is used to all Xtify delegation methods.
[[XLappMgr get] setDeveloperXidNotificationSelector:@selector(doUpdateDevServer:)];
```

Then you'd need to implement the method itself -

```
- (void) doUpdateXid:(XLappMgr *)appM
{
   NSLog(@"Got XID=%@",[appM getXid]);
   // Example, update the xid on developer's server 
}
```

You could find details [here](http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Advanced+Integration+Guide+for+Apple+Push+Notification+Service#AdvancedIntegrationGuideforApplePushNotificationService-GetNotifiedafterXtifyRegistration)